# Some Materials Not Rendering, But They Are Applied

Tags: rendering

For some reason some of my materials and textures aren't rendering when I do a full render (or even in the render viewport). I've attached an image below to demonstrate. Notice the front window frame and shutters are not rendering much texture at all. When I select the object in the viewport, all of a sudden the material renders. If I deselect, it goes back to the default gray.

[image]

Thanks for your help!

EDIT
I'm thinking it has something to do with these objects being "alt-D" duplicated instead of "shift-D". Could this be?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could add a little bit more info, like what render engine you are using and what does your material setup look like.  A .blend file uploaded to a site like [pasteall.org](http://www.pasteall.org/blend) would also be super helpful.  Thanks!

Comment: Oh, sorry. It's cycles and here's the blend file: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/33131

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some of your objects are duplicated.  In your .blend file, I selected one of the window shutters having problems showing materials.  I moved it away, and found there was still a shutter there.  One had material, and the other didn't.  Coinciding surfaces are unpredictable - you'll see parts of one and parts of the other mixed up, and exactly what you see  may change with camera position and viewpoint.

Solution is to find and delete those duplicate objects.